# How do I block people from outside my web server from seeing what technologies I'm using (e.g., Apache or PHP)?

Tags: php, security, apache, macos, webserver

I am running a test server locally that is also broadcasted (for education purposes) on a Mac. I ran a software called [acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com) from another computer and it was able to detect the technologies used on the server.

How can I prevent others from viewing the technology my server is running?

Comment: There is nothing bad in exposing such information. Your fears are groundless

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Exposing such information gives attackers data on exactly what versions of technologies are running on the site, so it becomes easier to know what exploits will work on that particular technology. Imagine that the system admin doesn't update PHP, and the version currently running has a known vulnerability - with information on the PHP version, the attackers knows exactly what vulnerability to exploit. If anything, hiding this information will at least slow down attackers.

Comment: This is probably a better question for serverfault.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel  I disagree,  you don't want to give the attacker any information.  There are platform specific attacks which could lead to a compromise,  you want the attacker to be noisy and slow.  Make him try every attack blindly and exhaust the most precious resource;  time.

Comment: Lol, @Rook stepped on his favorite ground. "How to make a bullet-proof defence for the site which nobody cares of" :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel thinking about how to break in or keep people out is often times more entertaining than real practical solutions.  That being said the first phase of a pen test is to gather information about the technologies/platforms that they are using.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/howto-hide-and-modify-apache-server-information-serversignature-and-servertokens-and-hide-php-version-x-powered-by/) is one thing you can do to hide the Apache, PHP and OS version information.

Before:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2009 12:20:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

After:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2009 13:06:21 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Also, make sure that you have custom error pages so that they don't reveal information about Apache and PHP.

Comment: thanks wow i wish this stuff was already checked off in httd.conf and php.ini. what im wondering now is, is there a way to hide server: apache as well?

Comment: @sarmenhb: Probably not by any normal / trivial means. But it's not bad to have that information in the headers, as many popular websites have it.

Comment: No, it's not possible to hide "Server: Apache" without re-compiling Apache. It wouldn't help either, since the first thing an attacker would test is probably Apache exploits anyway.

Answer (score 4):

1)Using [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) you can change your [ServerSignature](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/19399.html) to somthing compeltely different like this:

```
SecServerSignature "Microsoft IIS"
```

Without mod_security,  your http header will still say "Apache".

2)Even if you don't have a .php extension you can see if the file is a PHP file by doing this:

```
http://digg.com/?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
```

This url will display:[image]:

To stop this image hack and other issues, make sure this is set in your php.ini:

```
expose_php=Off
```

Also make sure:

```
display_errors=off
```

and:

```
session.name=session_id
```

3)For more fingerprinting try `nmap -sV yourdomain.com`,  often times ssh will leak detailed information like what Linux distro you are running.   I recommended disabling what you can and hiding the rest with [port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking).

Comment: ?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 ... damn it, didn't know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Iptables for linux, or use .htaccess file in www-root-dir

```
Order Deny,Allow

Deny from all

Allow from local.

Allow from 167.0.2.1, 167.0.2.2
```

or settings in httpd.conf

Comment: thanks, ive set something like that up already but was just wondering just incase i end up having a dedicated/virtual server one day.